# Trying to assign card pictures, but it gives me wrong cards

Tags: java, arrays

I have this method:
I am trying to assign picture of a card into their `iconCards[][]` profiles. Pictures are located in images/ folder as e.g. `images/AS.gif (Ace of Spades), images/AD.gif (Ace of Diamonds)` etc.

```
static void loadCardIcons(){
    int l =0;
    int k =0;

    while (k < 14){
        for (l = 0; l < 4; l++){
            String card = "images/" + Character.toString(valueRanks[k]) + "C.gif";
            iconCards[k][l] = new ImageIcon(card);
            System.out.println(k + " " + l + "   " + card);
            card = "images/" + Character.toString(valueRanks[k]) + "D.gif";
            iconCards[k][l++] = new ImageIcon(card);
            System.out.println(k + " " + l + "   " + card);
            card = "images/" + Character.toString(valueRanks[k]) + "H.gif";
            iconCards[k][l++] = new ImageIcon(card);
            System.out.println(k + " " + l + "   " + card);
            card = "images/" + Character.toString(valueRanks[k]) + "S.gif";
            iconCards[k][l++] = new ImageIcon(card);
            System.out.println(k + " " + l + "   " + card);
            k++;
        }
    }
    iconBack = new ImageIcon("images/BK.gif");
}


...12 3   images/KS.gif
13 0   images/XC.gif
13 1   images/XD.gif
13 2   images/XH.gif
13 3   images/XS.gif

*13
2
images/XS.gif*
```

You can see that `value = 13 and suit = 2`. According to output above the card should be `images/XH (JokerHearts)`, but it prints me XS. Why? Here's the method that runs it. Can't find out what's going on for weeks.

```
static public Icon getIcon(Card card){
    loadCardIcons();

    return iconCards[valueAsInt(card)][suitAsInt(card)];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here

```
iconCards[k][l++] = new ImageIcon(card);
```

`l++` is the post increment operator on `l`. Therefore given `l = 0` and `k = 0`, you would access

```
iconCards[0][0]
```

and then `l` would go to `1`. You might want to use the pre increment `++l` version.

So your `l` (as an index to `iconCards`) only goes up to value `2` (for `images/XH.gif`), not `3` (for `images/XS.gif`).

See the [Oracle tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) on increment/decrement operators for an explanation on their use.

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you very much, Sotirios!